# Use command module's getstatusoutput to execute a command that contains "here-document"

Tags: python, python-2.6

I'm unable to execute this command via `commands.getstatusoutput()` function.

```
from commands import getstatusoutput as x

command = """guestfish << _EOF_
add %s
run
mount /dev/sda1 /
write /etc/sysconfig/network "NETWORKING=yes\\nHOSTNAME=%s\\n"
_EOF_""" % ( "/tmp/foo", "foobar")

x(command)
```

Gives error:

```
sh: line 5: warning: here-document at line 0 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `_EOF_')
sh: -c: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

This looks like a really simple one but can't seem to figure it out. Just to make a note, `\\n` are intentional in the code.

Comment: Add a newline to the end of the string.

Comment: The terminating token must not have leading spaces.

Comment: Sorry guys, the answer is still not clear to me.